# Clipping more complicated shapes in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, clip

I have tried to understand TikZ clipping better but I am stuck. I'd like to clip the area bounded by the blue contour in this picture:

[image]

Unfortunately, the MWE is rather lengthy, and based on [Alain Matthes cool macros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46850/how-can-i-draw-an-arc-from-point-a-b-on-a-3d-sphere-in-tikz/49589#49589) and some additional macros from the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/406799/latitude-and-longitude-coordinates-on-a-sphere-using-tikz/406813#406813).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fadings,decorations.pathreplacing,shadings}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\newcommand\pgfmathsinandcos[3]{%
  \pgfmathsetmacro#1{sin(#3)}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro#2{cos(#3)}%
}
\newcommand\LongitudePlane[3][current plane]{%
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sinEl\cosEl{#2} % elevation
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sint\cost{#3} % azimuth
  \tikzset{#1/.style={cm={\cost,\sint*\sinEl,0,\cosEl,(0,0)}}}
}

\newcommand\LatitudePlane[3][current plane]{%
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sinEl\cosEl{#2} % elevation
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sint\cost{#3} % latitude
  \pgfmathsetmacro\yshift{\RadiusSphere*\cosEl*\sint}
  \tikzset{#1/.style={cm={\cost,0,0,\cost*\sinEl,(0,\yshift)}}} %
}
\newcommand\NewLatitudePlane[4][current plane]{%
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sinEl\cosEl{#3} % elevation
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sint\cost{#4} % latitude
  \pgfmathsetmacro\yshift{#2*\cosEl*\sint}
  \tikzset{#1/.style={cm={\cost,0,0,\cost*\sinEl,(0,\yshift)}}} %
}
\newcommand\DrawLongitudeCircle[2][1]{
  \LongitudePlane{\angEl}{#2}
  \tikzset{current plane/.prefix style={scale=#1}}
   % angle of "visibility"
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angVis{atan(sin(#2)*cos(\angEl)/sin(\angEl))} %
  \draw[current plane] (\angVis:1) arc (\angVis:\angVis+180:1);
  \draw[current plane,opacity=0.4] (\angVis-180:1) arc (\angVis-180:\angVis:1);
}
\newcommand\DrawLongitudeArc[4][black]{
  \LongitudePlane{\angEl}{#2}
  \tikzset{current plane/.prefix style={scale=1}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angVis{atan(sin(#2)*cos(\angEl)/sin(\angEl))} %
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angA{mod(max(\angVis,#3),360)} %
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angB{mod(min(\angVis+180,#4),360} %
  \draw[current plane,#1,opacity=0.4] (#3:\RadiusSphere) arc (#3:#4:\RadiusSphere);
  \draw[current plane,#1]  (\angA:\RadiusSphere) arc (\angA:\angB:\RadiusSphere);
}%
\newcommand\DrawLatitudeCircle[2][1]{
  \LatitudePlane{\angEl}{#2}
  \tikzset{current plane/.prefix style={scale=#1}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\sinVis{sin(#2)/cos(#2)*sin(\angEl)/cos(\angEl)}
  % angle of "visibility"
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angVis{asin(min(1,max(\sinVis,-1)))}
  \draw[current plane] (\angVis:1) arc (\angVis:-\angVis-180:1);
  \draw[current plane,opacity=0.4] (180-\angVis:1) arc (180-\angVis:\angVis:1);
}

\newcommand\DrawLatitudeArc[4][black]{
  \LatitudePlane{\angEl}{#2}
  \tikzset{current plane/.prefix style={scale=1}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\sinVis{sin(#2)/cos(#2)*sin(\angEl)/cos(\angEl)}
  % angle of "visibility"
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angVis{asin(min(1,max(\sinVis,-1)))}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angA{max(min(\angVis,#3),-\angVis-180)} %
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angB{min(\angVis,#4)} %
  \draw[current plane,#1,opacity=0.4] (#3:\RadiusSphere) arc (#3:#4:\RadiusSphere);
  \draw[current plane,#1] (\angA:\RadiusSphere) arc (\angA:\angB:\RadiusSphere);
}

%% document-wide tikz options and styles

\tikzset{%
  >=latex, % option for nice arrows
  inner sep=0pt,%
  outer sep=2pt,%
  mark coordinate/.style={inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum size=3pt,
    fill=black,circle}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} % "THE GLOBE" showcase
\def\RadiusSphere{4} % sphere radius
\def\angEl{20} % elevation angle
\def\angAz{-20} % azimuth angle

\shade[ball color = gray!40, opacity = 0.5] (0,0) circle (\RadiusSphere);

\tikzset{
    every path/.style={
        color=black
    }
}

\DrawLatitudeArc[blue]{40}{-140}{-30}
\DrawLongitudeArc[blue]{-140}{-30}{40}
\DrawLatitudeArc[blue]{-30}{-140}{-30}
\DrawLongitudeArc[blue]{-30}{-30}{40} 

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that, according to what I read, `clip` needs to be the only option of `\draw`, but this clashes with the way the arcs are drawn here. So I am wondering if there is a way to have both.

**EDIT** Motivated by the [great progress by John Kormylo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/410379/121799), I tried (and to some extent succeeded) to find alternative ways of shading the area. They are based on [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26664/121799), and require the [spath package](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/+branch/tex-sx/view/head:/spath.dtx) (run `pdflatex spath.dtx`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\usepackage{spath} % from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26664/121799
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fadings,decorations.pathreplacing,shadings}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\newcommand\pgfmathsinandcos[3]{%
  \pgfmathsetmacro#1{sin(#3)}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro#2{cos(#3)}%
}
\newcommand\LongitudePlane[3][current plane]{%
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sinEl\cosEl{#2} % elevation
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sint\cost{#3} % azimuth
  \tikzset{#1/.style={cm={\cost,\sint*\sinEl,0,\cosEl,(0,0)}}}
}

\newcommand\LatitudePlane[3][current plane]{%
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sinEl\cosEl{#2} % elevation
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sint\cost{#3} % latitude
  \pgfmathsetmacro\yshift{\RadiusSphere*\cosEl*\sint}
  \tikzset{#1/.style={cm={\cost,0,0,\cost*\sinEl,(0,\yshift)}}} %
}
\newcommand\NewLatitudePlane[4][current plane]{%
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sinEl\cosEl{#3} % elevation
  \pgfmathsinandcos\sint\cost{#4} % latitude
  \pgfmathsetmacro\yshift{#2*\cosEl*\sint}
  \tikzset{#1/.style={cm={\cost,0,0,\cost*\sinEl,(0,\yshift)}}} %
}
\newcommand\DrawLongitudeCircle[2][1]{
  \LongitudePlane{\angEl}{#2}
  \tikzset{current plane/.prefix style={scale=#1}}
   % angle of "visibility"
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angVis{atan(sin(#2)*cos(\angEl)/sin(\angEl))} %
  \draw[current plane] (\angVis:1) arc (\angVis:\angVis+180:1);
  \draw[current plane,opacity=0.4] (\angVis-180:1) arc (\angVis-180:\angVis:1);
}
\newcommand\DrawLongitudeArc[4][black]{
  \LongitudePlane{\angEl}{#2}
  \tikzset{current plane/.prefix style={scale=1}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angVis{atan(sin(#2)*cos(\angEl)/sin(\angEl))} %
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angA{mod(max(\angVis,#3),360)} %
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angB{mod(min(\angVis+180,#4),360} %
  \draw[current plane,#1,opacity=0.4] (#3:\RadiusSphere) arc (#3:#4:\RadiusSphere);
  \draw[current plane,#1]  (\angA:\RadiusSphere) arc (\angA:\angB:\RadiusSphere);
}%

\newcommand\ClipLongitudeArc[4][black]{
  \LongitudePlane{\angEl}{#2}
  \tikzset{current plane/.prefix style={scale=1}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angVis{atan(sin(#2)*cos(\angEl)/sin(\angEl))} %
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angA{mod(max(\angVis,#3),360)} %
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angB{mod(min(\angVis+180,#4),360} %
  \path[save path=\tmppathI,current plane,#1,opacity=0.4] (#3:\RadiusSphere) arc (#3:#4:\RadiusSphere);
  \path[save path=\tmppathII,current plane,#1]  (\angA:\RadiusSphere) arc (\angA:\angB:\RadiusSphere);
}%

\newcommand\ClipLongitudeArcReverse[4][black]{
  \LongitudePlane{\angEl}{#2}
  \tikzset{current plane/.prefix style={scale=1}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angVis{atan(sin(#2)*cos(\angEl)/sin(\angEl))} %
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angA{mod(max(\angVis,#3),360)} %
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angB{mod(min(\angVis+180,#4),360} %
  \path[save path=\tmppathI,current plane,#1,opacity=0.4] (#4:\RadiusSphere) arc (#4:#3:\RadiusSphere);
  \path[save path=\tmppathII,current plane,#1]  (\angB:\RadiusSphere) arc (\angB:\angA:\RadiusSphere);
}%

\newcommand\DrawLatitudeCircle[2][1]{
  \LatitudePlane{\angEl}{#2}
  \tikzset{current plane/.prefix style={scale=#1}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\sinVis{sin(#2)/cos(#2)*sin(\angEl)/cos(\angEl)}
  % angle of "visibility"
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angVis{asin(min(1,max(\sinVis,-1)))}
  \draw[current plane] (\angVis:1) arc (\angVis:-\angVis-180:1);
  \draw[current plane,opacity=0.4] (180-\angVis:1) arc (180-\angVis:\angVis:1);
}

\newcommand\DrawLatitudeArc[4][black]{
  \LatitudePlane{\angEl}{#2}
  \tikzset{current plane/.prefix style={scale=1}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\sinVis{sin(#2)/cos(#2)*sin(\angEl)/cos(\angEl)}
  % angle of "visibility"
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angVis{asin(min(1,max(\sinVis,-1)))}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angA{max(min(\angVis,#3),-\angVis-180)} %
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angB{min(\angVis,#4)} %
  \draw[current plane,#1,opacity=0.4] (#3:\RadiusSphere) arc (#3:#4:\RadiusSphere);
  \draw[current plane,#1] (\angA:\RadiusSphere) arc (\angA:\angB:\RadiusSphere);
}

\newcommand\ClipLatitudeArc[4][black]{
  \LatitudePlane{\angEl}{#2}
  \tikzset{current plane/.prefix style={scale=1}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\sinVis{sin(#2)/cos(#2)*sin(\angEl)/cos(\angEl)}
  % angle of "visibility"
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angVis{asin(min(1,max(\sinVis,-1)))}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angA{max(min(\angVis,#3),-\angVis-180)} %
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angB{min(\angVis,#4)} %
  \path[save path=\tmppathI,current plane,#1,opacity=0.4] (#3:\RadiusSphere) arc (#3:#4:\RadiusSphere);
  \path[save path=\tmppathII,current plane,#1] (\angA:\RadiusSphere) arc (\angA:\angB:\RadiusSphere);
}

\newcommand\ClipLatitudeArcReverse[4][black]{
  \LatitudePlane{\angEl}{#2}
  \tikzset{current plane/.prefix style={scale=1}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\sinVis{sin(#2)/cos(#2)*sin(\angEl)/cos(\angEl)}
  % angle of "visibility"
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angVis{asin(min(1,max(\sinVis,-1)))}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angA{max(min(\angVis,#3),-\angVis-180)} %
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angB{min(\angVis,#4)} %
  \path[save path=\tmppathI,current plane,#1,opacity=0.4] (#4:\RadiusSphere) arc (#4:#3:\RadiusSphere);
  \path[save path=\tmppathII,current plane,#1] (\angB:\RadiusSphere) arc (\angB:\angA:\RadiusSphere);
}


%% document-wide tikz options and styles

\tikzset{%
  >=latex, % option for nice arrows
  inner sep=0pt,%
  outer sep=2pt,%
  mark coordinate/.style={inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum size=3pt,
    fill=black,circle}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} % "THE GLOBE" showcase
\def\RadiusSphere{4} % sphere radius
\def\angEl{20} % elevation angle
\def\angAz{-20} % azimuth angle

\shade[ball color = gray!40, opacity = 0.5] (0,0) circle (\RadiusSphere);

\tikzset{
    every path/.style={
        color=black
    }
}

\ClipLatitudeArc[blue]{40}{-140}{-30}
\pgfoonew \patha=new spath(\tmppathI)
\pgfoonew \pathb=new spath(\tmppathII)
\ClipLongitudeArc[blue]{-30}{40}{-40} 
\pgfoonew \pathc=new spath(\tmppathI)
\pgfoonew \pathd=new spath(\tmppathII)
\ClipLatitudeArc[blue]{-40}{-30}{-140}
\pgfoonew \pathe=new spath(\tmppathI)
\pgfoonew \pathf=new spath(\tmppathII)
\ClipLongitudeArc[blue]{-140}{-30}{40}
\pgfoonew \pathg=new spath(\tmppathI)
\pgfoonew \pathh=new spath(\tmppathII)

\patha.concatenate with lineto(,\pathc)
\patha.concatenate with lineto(,\pathe)
\patha.concatenate with lineto(,\pathg)
\patha.close()

\patha.use path with tikz(line width=1pt,draw=black,fill=blue,path fading=south)

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Although this comes somewhat closer to what I wish to achieve, I am still puzzled that these paths can *not* be used for clippings. (This also means that John Kormylo's approach is much cleaner and better.) And I am wondering if there is a cleaner or at least alternative way that does not rely on the inofficial spath package.

Comment: Okay, the main problem is that the clip has to be one continuous path, and you have it subdivided.  That plus the whole [current plane] style which simply complicates matters.  Tell Alan Mathes that his macros are a pain.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I see what you mean but IMHO your code [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/162746/121799) is also quite sophisticated. Anyway, thanks a lot for your input and Happy New Year!

Comment: I worked out the math and have done some trial runs, but am having trouble converting my longitudes to yours.  I assume 0 longitude is at the center, in which case -140 is on the opposite side of the globe.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Oh WOW! These are not my longitudes, but they have been invented by Alain Matthes [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46850/how-can-i-draw-an-arc-from-point-a-b-on-a-3d-sphere-in-tikz/49589#49589). Yet I do not really understand what you mean by `0 longitude is at the center`. But most likely you only need to play with the azimuth angle `\angAz` in order to get coordinates that you like better (but I never did that).

Comment: It looks like 0 longitude is defined as right edge of the sphere, which is closer to arc angles.

Comment: Yes, you're right. And sorry, my comment on `\angAz` was nonsense.

Comment: Arrgh!  [rotate=...] doesn't work with arcs!  That kills that idea.

Comment: @JohnKormylo That sounds very cool. In *principle* one may get the boundaries also with circles in the respective planes and a lot of additional clipping, see samcarters comment to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/409367/121799).

Comment: I can do it using primatives like \pgfpatharcto and \pgfusepath{clip}.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Very exciting! Guess that will be relevant for many problems, including [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/410096/121799), even though cfr seems to disagree.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To clip, one must complete the border in a single path.  The easiest way to do this is to do everything using screen coordinates.

[image: math]

Unfortunately, `rotate` seems to have no effect on `arc`.  One can however use `\pgfpatharcto` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fadings,decorations.pathreplacing,shadings}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\newcommand{\location}[3][\empty]{% #1=label (optional) ,#2=latitude, #3=longitude
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\Xloc}{\RadiusSphere*cos(#2)*sin(#3-\Clong)}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\Yloc}{-\RadiusSphere*cos(#2)*sin(\Clat)*cos(#3-\Clong) + \RadiusSphere*sin(#2)*cos(\Clat)}%
  \ifx\empty#1\else
    \expandafter\let\csname Xloc#1\endcsname=\Xloc
    \expandafter\let\csname Yloc#1\endcsname=\Yloc
  \fi
}
% compute ellipse xradius=\RX, yradius=\RY, yshift=\CY, edge angles = \ArcStart, \ArcEnd
\newcommand{\latitude}[2][\empty]{% #1=label (optional), #2=latitude
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\RX}{\RadiusSphere*cos(#2)}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\RY}{\RX*sin(\Clat)}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\CY}{\RadiusSphere*sin(#2)*cos(\Clat)}%
  \pgfmathparse{tan(#2)*tan(\Clat)}%
  \pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(\pgfmathresult<1,\pgfmathresult,1)}%
  \pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(\pgfmathresult>-1,\pgfmathresult,-1)}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\ArcStart}{asin(\pgfmathresult)}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\ArcEnd}{-180-\ArcStart}%
  \ifx\empty#1\else
    \expandafter\let\csname RX#1\endcsname=\RX
    \expandafter\let\csname RY#1\endcsname=\RY
    \expandafter\let\csname CY#1\endcsname=\CY
    \expandafter\let\csname ArcStart#1\endcsname=\ArcStart
    \expandafter\let\csname ArcEnd#1\endcsname=\ArcEnd
  \fi
}
% compute ellipse rotation=\ROT, xradius=\RX, arc angle at equator=\LAT
\newcommand{\longitude}[2][\empty]{% #1=label (optional), #2=longitude
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\ROT}{atan2(sin(\Clat)*sin(#2-\Clong),cos(#2-\Clong))}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\LAT}{asin(cos(\Clat)*cos(\ROT))}% north pole
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\RX}{\RadiusSphere*tan(\LAT)*tan(\ROT)}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\LAT}{\LAT-90}%
  \ifx\empty#1\else
    \expandafter\let\csname ROT#1\endcsname=\ROT
    \expandafter\let\csname RX#1\endcsname=\RX
    \expandafter\let\csname LAT#1\endcsname=\LAT
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}% "THE GLOBE" showcase
\def\RadiusSphere{4}% sphere radius
\def\Clat{20}% point of view latitude
\def\Clong{-90}% point of view longitude

\latitude[A]{40}%
\latitude[B]{-30}%
\longitude[C]{-140}%
\longitude[D]{-30}%
\location[AC]{40}{-140}%
\location[AD]{40}{-30}%
\location[BC]{-30}{-140}%
\location[BD]{-30}{-30}%

\begin{scope}
  \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpointorigin}{\RadiusSphere cm}%
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointxy{\XlocAC}{\YlocAC}}%
  \pgfpatharcto{\RXA cm}{\RYA cm}{0}{0}{1}{\pgfpointxy{\XlocAD}{\YlocAD}}%
  \pgfpatharcto{\RXD cm}{\RadiusSphere cm}{\ROTD}{0}{0}{\pgfpointxy{\XlocBD}{\YlocBD}}%
  \pgfpatharcto{\RXB cm}{\RYB cm}{0}{0}{0}{\pgfpointxy{\XlocBC}{\YlocBC}}%
  \pgfpatharcto{\RXC cm}{\RadiusSphere cm}{\ROTC}{0}{0}{\pgfpointxy{\XlocAC}{\YlocAC}}%
  \pgfpathclose
  \pgfusepath{clip}%
  \shade[ball color = gray!40, opacity = 0.5] (0,0) circle (\RadiusSphere);
\end{scope}

\draw[blue] (0,\CYA) circle[x radius=\RXA, y radius=\RYA];
%\location{40}{\ArcStartA}%
%\draw[red] (\Xloc,\Yloc) arc[x radius=\RXA, y radius=\RYA, start angle=\ArcStartA, end angle=\ArcEndA];
\draw[blue] (0,\CYB) circle[x radius=\RXB, y radius=\RYB];
\draw[blue] (0,0) circle[x radius=\RXC, y radius=\RadiusSphere, rotate=\ROTC];
\draw[blue] (0,0) circle[x radius=\RXD, y radius=\RadiusSphere, rotate=\ROTD];

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

---

This code fragment performs the same function using `\pgfpatharcaxes`.  I didn't use this originally as it does not explicitly use rotate.

```
\begin{scope}
  \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpointorigin}{\RadiusSphere cm}%
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointxy{\XlocAC}{\YlocAC}}%
  \pgfpatharcaxes{-140}{-30}{\pgfpointxy{\RXA}{0}}{\pgfpointxy{0}{\RYA}}%
  \pgfpatharcaxes{40+\LATD}{-30+\LATD}{\pgfpointpolarxy{\ROTD}{\RXD}}%
    {\pgfpointpolarxy{\ROTD+90}{\RadiusSphere}}%
  \pgfpatharcaxes{-30}{-140}{\pgfpointxy{\RXB}{0}}{\pgfpointxy{0}{\RYB}}%
  \pgfpatharcaxes{-30+\LATC}{40+\LATC}{\pgfpointpolarxy{\ROTC}{\RXC}}%
    {\pgfpointpolarxy{\ROTC+90}{\RadiusSphere}}%
  \pgfpathclose
  \pgfusepath{clip}%
  \shade[ball color = gray!40, opacity = 0.5] (0,0) circle (\RadiusSphere);
\end{scope}
```

---

The following code fragment uses normal TikZ `\clip`.  It is based on [this question & answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/410849/why-doesnt-tikz-arc-support-rotate).

```
\begin{scope}
  \clip (0,0) circle[radius=\RadiusSphere] (\XlocAC,\YlocAC)
    arc[x radius=\RXA, y radius=\RYA, start angle=-140, end angle=-30]
    {[rotate=\ROTD] arc[x radius=\RXD, y radius=\RadiusSphere,
      start angle={40+\LATD}, end angle={-30+\LATD}]}
    arc[x radius=\RXB, y radius=\RYB, start angle=-30, end angle=-140]
    {[rotate=\ROTC] arc[x radius=\RXC, y radius=\RadiusSphere,
      start angle={-30+\LATC}, end angle={40+\LATC}]}
    -- cycle;
  \shade[ball color = gray!40, opacity = 0.5] (0,0) circle (\RadiusSphere);
\end{scope}
```

Comment: This is great! Your parametrizations seem so much simpler than the above ones!

Comment: I also updated my post by an alternative method that partially successful. I'd like to ask you whether you recommend to post this as a separate question.

Comment: I added a solution which does not use pgf primatives.