# Problems drawing a sleeping duck

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzducks

I'm trying to draw a sleeping duck, using the extremely cool tikzducks.sty. And I encounter two problems. To explain them, let me present the MWE first.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzducks}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=9] % changing the scale to 1 (or even somewhat larger values) fails
 \duck[eye=yellow!50!brown,pupil=yellow!50!brown]
        \begin{scope}[ultra thick,rotate=-20,decoration={ticks,raise=-4,amplitude=4,segment length=8
        }]
        \draw[decorate] (0.161,1.682) arc [start angle=220, end angle=320,x radius=0.0893, y radius=0.125];
%       \draw[decorate] (0.23,1.7675) ellipse (0.0893 and 0.125); %from tikzducks.sty
        \draw[decorate] (-0.06,1.74) ellipse (0.0786 and 0.1143); %from tikzducks.sty
%       \draw[decorate] (-0.125,1.67) arc [start angle=220, end angle=320,x radius=0.0893, y radius=0.125];
        \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The right eye (OK, the duck would say it's her left eye) is roughly as I want it to be. However, I had to move the center of the ellipse whose arc I was drawing relative to the values found in tikzducks.sty. On the left I I drew the complete ellipse, and no adjustment of the coordinates was necessary. (Of course, ultimately I'd like only a arc here, too.) So my first question is whether one can draw an elliptical arc sitting on the ellipse without adjusting this coordinate.

What is more, if I downscale the picture, i.e. remove the `[scale=9]` after `begin{tikzpicture}`, the compilation fails with a `! Dimension too large.` error. Is there a way to fix this? (Or do the ducks have to stay awake all the time? ;-)

Comment: An ellipse is drawn with the pen (coordinate before `ellipse`, (0.23,1.7675) in this case) initially located on its center. While an arc is drawn with the pen located on the starting point, which in this case should be over the ellipse.

Comment: @Ignasi Thanks, I am aware of this. (Perhaps I should have written this.) My question is whether one can only draw a part of an ellipse with the placement coinciding with the one of the full ellipse -- the above is an example for a situation where this could be useful.

Comment: @marmot you could draw the full ellipse and clip to the part you want to see.

Comment: @samcarter That's a great suggestion! Then the "only" remaining problem is the `Dimension too large` error.

Comment: Personally, I would let sleeping ducks lie.

Comment: ooh a duck-friendly marmot! ♥

Comment: @AlanMunn be my guest ;-)

Comment: @PauloCereda Well, if there is one thing marmots are good at (apart from eating, of course), it's sleeping ;-)

Comment: Am I alone in pronouncing 'slee-ping duck' to rhyme with 'Peking duck'?

Comment: @AlanMunn But they're not ;).

Comment: @cfr lie has two meanings, either being in a horizontal position, which they don't, or not telling the truth, which will be hard to express in a simple picture (unless you want to prove me lies;-)

Comment: @marmot They are surely in a horizontal position. Vertical would be 'heads down, tails up' (or, I guess, tails down, heads up, but that seems rather less likely from a physiological point of view). 'Lie' has more than two meanings ....

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I wouldn't use decorate. You run into problems at different scales, also you can't really fine tune the length. I would draw the eyelashes one by one, and perhaps even bend some. As the line width doesn't scale, some style to adapt the lashes will be needed. A sleeping mask is perhaps easier ;-).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzducks}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1] 
\duck

\path[rotate=-20]
    (0.23,1.7675)coordinate(ECR) ellipse (0.0893 and 0.125);

\path[rotate=-20]
    (-0.06,1.74)coordinate(ECL) ellipse (0.0786 and 0.1143);

\foreach \x/\y in {0/1,1/2,2/3,3/3.3,4/3,5/2,6/1.4}
{ \draw[brown!50!black,rotate=-20,line cap=round] (ECR)--++(\x*15+220:0.11cm+\y*0.012cm); };

\foreach \x/\y in {0/1,1/2,2/3,3/3.3,4/3,5/2,6/1.4}
{ \draw[brown!50!black,rotate=-20,line cap=round] (ECL)--++(\x*15+220:0.11cm+\y*0.009cm); };
%
%
\fill[rotate=-20,yellow!50!brown]
    (0.23,1.7675) ellipse (0.0893 and 0.125);
%
\fill[rotate=-20,yellow!50!brown]
    (-0.06,1.74) ellipse (0.0786 and 0.1143);

\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5] % changing the scale to 1 (or even somewhat larger values) fails
\duck

\path[rotate=-20]
    (0.23,1.7675)coordinate(ECR) ellipse (0.0893 and 0.125);

\path[rotate=-20]
    (-0.06,1.74)coordinate(ECL) ellipse (0.0786 and 0.1143);

\begin{scope}[ultra thick]
\foreach \x/\y in {0/1,1/2,2/3,3/3.3,4/3,5/2,6/1.4}
{ \draw[brown!50!black,rotate=-20,line cap=round] (ECR)--++(\x*15+220:0.11cm+\y*0.012cm); };

\foreach \x/\y in {0/1,1/2,2/3,3/3.3,4/3,5/2,6/1.4}
{ \draw[brown!50!black,rotate=-20,line cap=round] (ECL)--++(\x*15+220:0.11cm+\y*0.009cm); };
\end{scope}
%
%
\fill[rotate=-20,yellow!50!brown]
    (0.23,1.7675) ellipse (0.0893 and 0.125);
%
\fill[rotate=-20,yellow!50!brown]
    (-0.06,1.74) ellipse (0.0786 and 0.1143);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please feel free to undo my edit. Due to perspective the left eye is a bit smaller.

Comment: @samcarter no its fine, that was a copy&paste error.

Comment: Very nice! Sleep well!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Also works very well the other way round: https://i.stack.imgur.com/379Hp.png

Comment: @samcarter ;-) (but my husband complains that next there will be lipsticks ...).

Comment: :) `\duck[bill=pink]`

Comment: Do ducks have eyelashes?

Comment: Some birds have little hairlike feathers being what amounts to eyelashes; there's a very clear example [here](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/42/f0/6a/42f06a94a5a67dd839d8de8e196985d0.jpg); secretary birds have prominent ones also; and you can sometimes see teeny ones on a budgie as [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVQ0o.png);  I don't think ducks will in general though. But this is a cartoon duck and it can have lashes if it wants.

Comment: @cfr Those who grow beards do ;-)

Answer (score 5):

A solution with an updated version of veclen. I used xfp. The problem is the same with my macro `\tkzMarkAngle`. I used the library **decoration** and an error appeared with small angle's value.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzducks,xfp}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\makeatletter
\let\pgfmath@function@veclen\relax
\pgfmathdeclarefunction*{veclen}{2}{%
\begingroup%
    \pgfmath@x#1pt\relax%
    \pgfmath@y#2pt\relax%
    \pgf@xa=\pgf@x%
    \pgf@ya=\pgf@y%
    \edef\tkz@temp@a{\fpeval{\pgfmath@tonumber{\pgf@xa}}}
    \edef\tkz@temp@b{\fpeval{\pgfmath@tonumber{\pgf@ya}}}
    \edef\tkz@temp@sum{\fpeval{%
        (\tkz@temp@a*\tkz@temp@a+\tkz@temp@b*\tkz@temp@b)}}
    \edef\tkz@xfpMathLen{\fpeval{sqrt(\tkz@temp@sum)}}
%\edef\pgfmath@tmp{\fpeval{round(\tkzFPMathLen,6)}}
%\pgfmath@tmp %
    \pgfmath@returnone\tkz@xfpMathLen pt%
\endgroup%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1] % changing the scale to 1 (or even somewhat larger values) fails
 \duck[eye=yellow!50!brown,pupil=yellow!50!brown]
        \begin{scope}[line width=.4pt,rotate=-20,decoration={ticks,raise=-.5,amplitude=.5,segment length=1.5
        }]
        \draw[decorate] (0.161,1.682) arc [start angle=220, end angle=320,x radius=0.0893, y radius=0.125];
       \draw[decorate] (-0.125,1.67) arc [start angle=220, end angle=320,x radius=0.0893, y radius=0.125];
        \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]