# Spikes around circle using tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf

Recently I have been mailing with a lector on the institute of Niels Bohr in Copenhagen regarding a picture written in LaTeX of two inertialframes. He made a figure that looks like this:
[image]

He used the pstricks package, and he sent me the code. Though, my LaTeX couldn't run with the code, so I tried to make the picture using tikzpicture. I rewrote this code:

```
    \begin{figure}
\begin{center}
  \psset{unit=8.5mm}
  \begin{pspicture}(-3,-2.4)(14,3.5)
    \psset{linewidth=0.7pt}
    \psset{arrowsize=6pt}
%
    \rput(0,0){
      \psline[linewidth=1pt]{->}(0,0)(3.3,0)   \rput(3.3,-0.5){$x$}
      \psline[linewidth=1pt]{->}(0,0)(0,3.3)   \rput(-0.5,3.2){$y$}
      \psline[linewidth=1pt]{->}(0,0)(-2,-1.7) \rput(-2.1,-2.1){$z$}
       \rput[l](0.5,3.3){\textsf{S}}
    }
%
    \rput(7,0){
      \psline[linewidth=1pt]{->}(0,0)(3.3,0)   \rput(3.3,-0.5){$x^\prime$}
      \psline[linewidth=1pt]{->}(0,0)(0,3.3)   \rput(-0.5,3.2){$y^\prime$}
      \psline[linewidth=1pt]{->}(0,0)(-2,-1.7) \rput(-2.1,-2.1){$z^\prime$}
      \rput[l](0.5,3.3){\textsf{S}$^\prime$}
    }
%
    \psline{->}(5.5,2.2)(8.5,2.2) \rput(8.8,2.2){$v$}
    \rput(11,2.2){\scalebox{2}{\ding{90}}}
    \pscircle[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid](11,2.2){0.2}
    \psdots[dotsize=4pt](11,2.2)
    \rput[c](11,3){\small \textsf{Begivenhed}}
    \rput[l](11.7,2.4){\small $(x,\,y,\,z,\,t)$}
    \rput[l](11.7,1.8){\small $(x^\prime,\,y^\prime,\,z^\prime,\,t^\prime)$}
    \psline{|->}(0.2,1.4)(6.8,1.4)     \rput(3.5,1.7){$vt$}
    \psline{|->}(7.2,1.4)(11,1.4)      \rput(9.1,1.7){$x^\prime$}
    \psline{|->}(0.2,0.8)(11,0.8)      \rput(5.6,1.1){$x$}
  \end{pspicture}
  \caption{En begivenhed betragtes fra to referencesystemer i
    standardkonfigurationen.}
  \label{fig:standardkonfig}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

into this converted code in tikz:

```
\begin{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate[label= below left:$$] (origo) at (0,0);

\coordinate[label = below left:$$] (origos) at (7,0);

\draw[line width = 1pt, -{Stealth[length=3mm]}] (origo) -- (3.3,0) node[below]{$x$};

\draw[line width = 1pt, -{Stealth[length=3mm]}] (origo) -- (0,3.3) node[left]{$y$};

\draw[line width= 1pt, -{Stealth[length=3mm]}] (origo) -- (-2,-1.7) node[below]{$z$};

\node[] at (0.5,3.3) {\textsf{S}};

\begin{scope}[xshift = 7cm]

\draw[line width = 1pt, -{Stealth[length=3mm]}] (0,0) -- (3.3,0) node[below]{$x'$};

\draw[line width = 1pt, -{Stealth[length=3mm]}] (0,0) -- (0,3.3) node[left]{$y'$};

\draw[line width= 1pt, -{Stealth[length=3mm]}] (0,0) -- (-2,-1.7) node[below]{$z'$};

\node[] at (0.5,3.3) {\textsf{S}$^{\prime}$};

\end{scope}

\draw[-{Stealth[length=3mm]}, line width=0.8pt](5.5,2.2) -- (8.5,2.2) node[right]{$v$};

\fill[black] (11,2.2) circle (4pt);

\node[] at (11,3) {\small \textsf{Begivenhed}};

\node[] at (12.3,2.4) {\small $(t, \, x, \, y, \, z)$};

\node[] at (12.5,1.8) {\small $(t', \, x', \, y', \, z')$};

\draw[|-{Stealth[length=3mm]}, line width=0.8pt] (0.2,1.4) -- (6.8,1.4) node[above] at (3.5,1.4) {$vt$};

\draw[|-{Stealth[length=3mm]}, line width=0.8pt] (7.2,1.4) -- (11,1.4) node[above] at (9.1,1.4) {$x^{\prime}$};

\draw[|-{Stealth[length=3mm]},line width=0.8pt] (0.2,0.8) -- (11,0.8) node[above] at (5.6,0.76) {$x$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}
```

The result was this:
[image]
Which is almost entirely the same, except for the circle that on the ps-code looks like a sun, but on my code (tikz) is just a dot. Does any of you have an idea of how to create that little thing?

FYI, 'Begivenhed', which is a danish word, means event and is used in special relativity. That little sun is supposed to be an event.

Comment: I had the same idea as Stefan, so no point in adding another answer, but some other suggestions for the code: https://gist.github.com/TorbjornT/b0b26add1c44b16a79bd7d37c4e991dc

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use polar coordinates to draw the lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate[label= below left:$$] (origo) at (0,0);
    \coordinate[label = below left:$$] (origos) at (7,0);
    \draw[line width = 1pt, -{Stealth[length=3mm]}] (origo) -- (3.3,0) node[below]{$x$};
    \draw[line width = 1pt, -{Stealth[length=3mm]}] (origo) -- (0,3.3) node[left]{$y$};
    \draw[line width= 1pt, -{Stealth[length=3mm]}] (origo) -- (-2,-1.7) node[below]{$z$};
    \node[] at (0.5,3.3) {\textsf{S}};
    \begin{scope}[xshift = 7cm]
      \draw[line width = 1pt, -{Stealth[length=3mm]}] (0,0) -- (3.3,0) node[below]{$x'$};
      \draw[line width = 1pt, -{Stealth[length=3mm]}] (0,0) -- (0,3.3) node[left]{$y'$};
      \draw[line width= 1pt, -{Stealth[length=3mm]}] (0,0) -- (-2,-1.7) node[below]{$z'$};
      \node[] at (0.5,3.3) {\textsf{S}$^{\prime}$};
    \end{scope}
    \draw[-{Stealth[length=3mm]}, line width=0.8pt](5.5,2.2) -- (8.5,2.2) node[right]{$v$};
    \fill[black] (11,2.2) circle (4pt);
    \foreach \ang in {22.5,45,...,360}{%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Added
      \draw[ultra thick] (11,2.2) +(\ang:6pt) -- +(\ang:11pt);
    }
    \node[] at (11,3) {\small \textsf{Begivenhed}};
    \node[] at (12.3,2.4) {\small $(t, \, x, \, y, \, z)$};
    \node[] at (12.5,1.8) {\small $(t', \, x', \, y', \, z')$};
    \draw[|-{Stealth[length=3mm]}, line width=0.8pt] (0.2,1.4) -- (6.8,1.4) node[above] at (3.5,1.4) {$vt$};
    \draw[|-{Stealth[length=3mm]}, line width=0.8pt] (7.2,1.4) -- (11,1.4) node[above] at (9.1,1.4) {$x^{\prime}$};
    \draw[|-{Stealth[length=3mm]},line width=0.8pt] (0.2,0.8) -- (11,0.8) node[above] at (5.6,0.76) {$x$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this looks just like that. Though, I'm not quite experienced with tikz, so could to elaborate on why the code looks like it does? Could you perhaps break the syntax down for me, the arch, ang:6pt ++ and so on? :)

Comment: `\ang` is the angle of the line and the `\foreach` loops through the 16 values. For each line start in the center of your black circle and go 6pt in the angle direction, where you start draw the line up to 11pt. The notation `(\ang:6pt)` means `6pt` in the direction `\ang`.

Answer (score 12):

In the original code, you can see that the symbol is generated by `\ding{90}`.

As the preamble is missing in both your code examples, one has to guess, but it turns out the command comes from the `pifont` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\usepackage{pifont}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate[label= below left:$$] (origo) at (0,0);

\coordinate[label = below left:$$] (origos) at (7,0);

\draw[line width = 1pt, -{Stealth[length=3mm]}] (origo) -- (3.3,0) node[below]{$x$};

\draw[line width = 1pt, -{Stealth[length=3mm]}] (origo) -- (0,3.3) node[left]{$y$};

\draw[line width= 1pt, -{Stealth[length=3mm]}] (origo) -- (-2,-1.7) node[below]{$z$};

\node[] at (0.5,3.3) {\textsf{S}};

\begin{scope}[xshift = 7cm]

\draw[line width = 1pt, -{Stealth[length=3mm]}] (0,0) -- (3.3,0) node[below]{$x'$};

\draw[line width = 1pt, -{Stealth[length=3mm]}] (0,0) -- (0,3.3) node[left]{$y'$};

\draw[line width= 1pt, -{Stealth[length=3mm]}] (0,0) -- (-2,-1.7) node[below]{$z'$};

\node[] at (0.5,3.3) {\textsf{S}$^{\prime}$};

\end{scope}

\draw[-{Stealth[length=3mm]}, line width=0.8pt](5.5,2.2) -- (8.5,2.2) node[right]{$v$};

%\fill[black] (11,2.2) circle (4pt);

\node[scale=3] at (11,2.2) {\ding{90}};

\node[] at (11,3) {\small \textsf{Begivenhed}};

\node[] at (12.3,2.4) {\small $(t, \, x, \, y, \, z)$};

\node[] at (12.5,1.8) {\small $(t', \, x', \, y', \, z')$};

\draw[|-{Stealth[length=3mm]}, line width=0.8pt] (0.2,1.4) -- (6.8,1.4) node[above] at (3.5,1.4) {$vt$};

\draw[|-{Stealth[length=3mm]}, line width=0.8pt] (7.2,1.4) -- (11,1.4) node[above] at (9.1,1.4) {$x^{\prime}$};

\draw[|-{Stealth[length=3mm]},line width=0.8pt] (0.2,0.8) -- (11,0.8) node[above] at (5.6,0.76) {$x$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This is one of the cases where the `decoration` with `ticks` doesn't work because the dimensions get too small.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate[label= below left:${}$] (origo) at (0,0);

\coordinate[label = below left:${}$] (origos) at (7,0);

\draw[line width = 1pt, -{Stealth[length=3mm]}] (origo) -- (3.3,0) node[below]{$x$};

\draw[line width = 1pt, -{Stealth[length=3mm]}] (origo) -- (0,3.3) node[left]{$y$};

\draw[line width= 1pt, -{Stealth[length=3mm]}] (origo) -- (-2,-1.7) node[below]{$z$};

\node[] at (0.5,3.3) {\textsf{S}};

\begin{scope}[xshift = 7cm]

\draw[line width = 1pt, -{Stealth[length=3mm]}] (0,0) -- (3.3,0) node[below]{$x'$};

\draw[line width = 1pt, -{Stealth[length=3mm]}] (0,0) -- (0,3.3) node[left]{$y'$};

\draw[line width= 1pt, -{Stealth[length=3mm]}] (0,0) -- (-2,-1.7) node[below]{$z'$};

\node[] at (0.5,3.3) {\textsf{S}$^{\prime}$};


\end{scope}

\draw[-{Stealth[length=3mm]}, line width=0.8pt](5.5,2.2) -- (8.5,2.2) node[right]{$v$};

\foreach \X in {0,30,...,330}
{\draw (11,2.2) -- ++ (\X:11pt);}
\fill[white] (11,2.2) circle (6pt);
\fill[black] (11,2.2) circle (4pt);


\node[] at (11,3) {\small \textsf{Begivenhed}};

\node[] at (12.3,2.4) {\small $(t, \, x, \, y, \, z)$};

\node[] at (12.5,1.8) {\small $(t', \, x', \, y', \, z')$};

\draw[|-{Stealth[length=3mm]}, line width=0.8pt] (0.2,1.4) -- (6.8,1.4) node[above] at (3.5,1.4) {$vt$};

\draw[|-{Stealth[length=3mm]}, line width=0.8pt] (7.2,1.4) -- (11,1.4) node[above] at (9.1,1.4) {$x^{\prime}$};

\draw[|-{Stealth[length=3mm]},line width=0.8pt] (0.2,0.8) -- (11,0.8) node[above] at (5.6,0.76) {$x$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I changed `ticks` to `tikz` :). And can't you fool `ticks` by making a bigger symbol and scaling it afterward? **EDIT:** Sorry if I misunderstood it!

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Sorry, `ticks` was intentional, and I'm not sure scaling would work, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/409367/problems-drawing-a-sleeping-duck).

Answer (score 4):

It is not a complete an excellent answer. But is also possible to create a macro
for `TikZ` using this code.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\Radius{4cm}
  \draw[line width=1.2mm]
    \foreach \a in {0,10,20, 30, ..., 350} {
      (0, 0) -- (\a:\Radius)
    }
    (0, 0) -- (10:3cm)
  ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```