# Curved brace decoration

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations

As far as I know the `brace` decoration is only available for straight lines, as in the following example :

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={brace,raise=2pt}]
    \draw [postaction={draw,decorate,red}] (0,0) to[bend left] (3,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Do you khow how can I use (define ?) a `curved brace` decoration that follows an arbitrary (not only straight) path.
And if possible that have not only the standard parameters `raise`, `mirror`, but also a `bump position` that is by default `.5` and that set the position of the middle "bump" of the brace.

Thanks in advance for your help.

[image]

Comment: [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45129/121799) is a solution for circular arcs.

Comment: Marmot, thanks for the link. But I'm looking for a decoration, not for instructions to draw a particular one. And I like the "shape" of the original `brace`. The only problem for me is that it do not follow the curve. And I don't know how to make a decoration that is a mixture between `brace` and `curveto`.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a first (!) proposal. It does some braces along arbitrary paths. The way it works is that there is recording phase, to which you pass the path. In this phase you can also specify keys. In the present version these are `raise` and `mirror` but this is up to negotiations. ;-) The second phase draws the brace. I added a simpleminded proposal but as before I will be happy to address constructive inputs that tell me how the appearance can be improved. Constructing a brace along the path you have in your MWE becomes as simple as saying

```
\path[record path]  (0,0) to[bend left] (3,1);
\draw[brace];
```

BTW, if anyone is even thinking of making this a one-step procedure by employing `\pgfextra` (or something equivalent): **PLEASE DON'T!** If you have another way that is *robust* I am all ears. Here is the code.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\newcounter{bracep}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[record path/.style={/utils/exec=\tikzset{bent brace/.cd,#1},
    decorate,decoration={markings,mark=at position 0 with
    {\setcounter{bracep}{1}%\typeout{\pgfdecoratedpathlength}
    \path(0pt,{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/bent brace/scale}*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/bent brace/raise}})
     coordinate (bracep-\number\value{bracep});
     \pgfmathsetmacro{\mystep}{(\pgfdecoratedpathlength-4pt)/int(1+(\pgfdecoratedpathlength-4pt)/2pt)}
     \xdef\mystep{\mystep}},
    mark=between positions 2pt and {\pgfdecoratedpathlength-2pt} step \mystep pt with {\stepcounter{bracep}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itest}{
    ifthenelse(abs(\number\value{bracep}*2pt/\pgfdecoratedpathlength-0.5)<1pt/\pgfdecoratedpathlength,1,0)}
    \coordinate (bracep-\number\value{bracep}) at
    (0,{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/bent brace/scale}*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/bent brace/raise}+2pt+\itest*2pt)})
    \ifnum\itest=1
     node[transform shape,bent brace/nodes]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/bent brace/text}}
    \fi;},
    mark=at position 1 with {\stepcounter{bracep}
    \coordinate (bracep-\number\value{bracep}) at (0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/bent brace/scale}*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/bent brace/raise});}
    }},brace/.style={insert path={plot[smooth,samples at={1,...,\number\value{bracep}},variable=\x]
    (bracep-\x)}},
    bent brace/.cd,raise/.initial=0pt,scale/.initial=1,text/.initial={},
    nodes/.style={},node options/.code=\tikzset{bent brace/nodes/.append style=#1},
    mirror/.code={\tikzset{bent brace/scale=-1}}]
    \path[postaction={record path={text=stuff,node options={above,text depth=0.5ex}}},draw,ultra thin]  (0,0) to[bend left](3,1);
    \draw[brace];
    \path[postaction={record path={raise=4pt}},draw,ultra thin]  (3,1) to[bend left] (3,-2);
    \draw[blue,brace];
    \path[postaction={record path={mirror,text={more stuff},node
    options={red,below}}},draw,ultra thin] (0,0) 
    to[bend right] (3,-2);
    \draw[red,brace];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The ultra thin paths are just to show the paths that get braced, and the code also has examples of some text above or below the center of the brace. Of course, one may want to combine this with `decorations.text` to bend the text as well.

Comment: One of a wonderful suggestion again from you....

Comment: Thanks Marmot for all your efforts ! I'm sure I'll learn a lot from your code. But I'm really looking for a decoration not for some other way to do a curved brace. Since I asked the question I discovered `\pgfdeclaredecoration` in the manual. I hope that somebody will be able to show me how to do this. Thanks one more time.

Comment: When I try `\draw[record path,smooth]  plot coordinates{(3,1) (3,-2) (1,-1)};` tex throw an error `! Dimension too large.`. Any Idea ?

Comment: @mefortex Decorations will also have problems with `\draw plot[smooth] coordinates{(3,1) (3,-2) (1,-1)};` because the curvature is rather high. Here the error comes from `decorations.markings`. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/409367/121799 for a related discussion and to see that this is not restricted to `decorations.markings`. (And I am aware of `\pgfdeclaredecoration`, I was using it many times, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/449706/121799.)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and the links !

Answer (score 4):

One option for this would be to define new arrow tips that do the curved ends.  This would mean that the brace would exactly follow the original path (except at the ends) rather than being offset, and the easiest way to put the central bump in would be to manually break the path.  Nevertheless, there's a simplicity to the idea that I quite like.  (I did have a look at the decoration route, but looking was as far as I got.)

```latex
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/492887/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\pgfdeclarearrow{%
  name=Brace tip,
  parameters = {%
    \the\pgfarrowlength
    \the\pgfarrowlinewidth
  },
  setup code = {
    \pgfarrowssettipend{.5\pgfarrowlength}
    \pgfarrowssetlineend{-.45\pgfarrowlength}
    \pgfarrowssetvisualbackend{-.5\pgfarrowlength}
    \pgfarrowssetbackend{-.5\pgfarrowlength}
    \pgfarrowshullpoint{.5\pgfarrowlength}{.5\pgfarrowlength}
    \pgfarrowshullpoint{.5\pgfarrowlength}{-.5\pgflinewidth}
    \pgfarrowshullpoint{-.5\pgfarrowlength}{.5\pgflinewidth}
    \pgfarrowshullpoint{-.5\pgfarrowlength}{-.5\pgflinewidth}
    \pgfarrowssavethe\pgfarrowlength
  },
  drawing code = {
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-.5\pgfarrowlength}{.5\pgflinewidth}}%
    \pgfpathcurveto%
    {\pgfqpoint{.2\pgfarrowlength}{.5\pgflinewidth}}%
    {\pgfpoint{.5\pgfarrowlength-.25\pgflinewidth}{.05\pgfarrowlength}}%
    {\pgfpoint{.5\pgfarrowlength}{.5\pgfarrowlength}}%
    \pgfpathcurveto%
    {\pgfpoint{.5\pgfarrowlength+.25\pgflinewidth}{.05\pgfarrowlength}}%
    {\pgfqpoint{.2\pgfarrowlength}{-.5\pgflinewidth}}%
    {\pgfqpoint{-.5\pgfarrowlength}{-.5\pgflinewidth}}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{-.5\pgfarrowlength}{.5\pgflinewidth}}
    \pgfpathclose
    \pgfusepathqfill
  },
  defaults = {
    length = .5cm,
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[Brace tip-Brace tip,ultra thick] (0,0) .. controls +(2,0) and +(0,-2) .. (4,4);
\draw[{Brace tip[swap]}-{Brace tip[swap]},ultra thick] (4,4) .. controls +(0,2) and +(-2,0) .. (8,8);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Brace along curve]

Comment: Nice ! I think that this is what is used by Qrrbrbirlbel in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82930/189842) pointed to me by Marmot. Why should we define new arrow in place to use `Computer Modern Rightarrow` with `left`, `right`, `harpoon` and if necessary `reversed` options ?

Comment: I guess it's a similar idea - I hadn't seen that answer.  I have a small preference for tapered ends as in this one.

I don't really understand your question, though.

Comment: Sorry to not being clear in my question. My question is : why we should define a new arrow tip and not simply using existing one like for example `\draw[{Computer Modern Rightarrow[left,reversed]}-{Computer Modern Rightarrow[left,reversed]}] (0,0) .. controls +(2,0) and +(0,-2) .. (4,4);\draw[{Computer Modern Rightarrow[right,reversed]}-{Computer Modern Rightarrow[right,reversed]}] (4,4) .. controls +(0,2) and +(-2,0) .. (8,8);` ?

Comment: Oh sorry, I see now : your arrow tip is nicer (it goes thin at the end) and the join in the middle is perfect. Thanks for showing me how we can define this arrow tips !

Comment: The *other* reason being that I was unaware of that arrow tip!  So I've learnt something too.