# Why doesn't TikZ arc support rotate?

Tags: tikz-pgf

It is easy enough to implement using `\pgfpatharcaxes` and `\pgfpointpolarxy`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[red] (0,0) arc[x radius=2, y radius=1, rotate=-45,
    start angle=0, end angle=180];

  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
  \pgfpatharcaxes{0}{180}{\pgfpointpolarxy{-45}{2}}%
    {\pgfpointpolarxy{-45+90}{1}}
  \pgfusepath{draw}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Give it to `\draw` as an option

Comment: @percusse - I was trying to use it with \clip (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/408245/clipping-more-complicated-shapes-in-tikz/410379#410379).

Comment: You can also add `[rotate=-45]` just **before** `arc[...]`: `\draw[red] (0,0) [rotate=-45] arc[x radius=2, y radius=1,  start angle=0, end angle=180];`.

Comment: @PaulGaborit - I wasn't aware the TikZ parser could do that.  Would you like to submit that as an answer to close the question?

Comment: @JohnKormylo See p.146, pgfmanual, v3.0.1a: _At any point where TikZ expects a path operation, you can also give some graphic options, which is a
list of options in brackets_...

Comment: One could use the same protocol to implement rotate with circle, BUT YOU DON'T HAVE TO!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TikZ `arc` uses PGF `\pgfpatharc` and it doesn't have flexibility in adding transformations.

Instead you can add a inline scope

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[red] (0,0) --(1,1) {[rotate=-45] arc[x radius=2, y radius=1, start angle=0,
           end angle=180] -- (-1,1)} -- (-1,1) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: In your example, the inline scope is not required...

Comment: I noticed that the effect is cumulative otherwise.

Comment: @PaulGaborit Added an example for which you need one

Comment: @percusse This new example is much better. ;-)