# Reverse TikZ stroke direction to use with fill rules

Tags: tikz-pgf, fill, clip

This question is inspired by my own answer:
[How to draw the crossings in a tikz picture?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/568940/how-to-draw-the-crossings-in-a-tikz-picture/568980#568980)
where I draw the blue ellipse in four stages. I was thinking that it should be possible to draw with only one `\fill` command. To make the correct `\clip`, I need to understand the default `\clip` or `\fill` non-Zero Winding Rule, the `nonzero rule` (the manual 15.5.2  page 181) and not the `even odd rule`.

---

In this example, we can see that circles(and ellipses) are drawn with reverse stroke compared to rectangles:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[fill=red]  (0,0) circle (1) (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
 \draw[fill=green] (4,-1) rectangle (6,1) (5,0) rectangle (7,2);
 \draw[fill=blue] (9,0) circle (1) (9.5,0.5) circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Overlapping circles and rectangles. The red circle and rectangle overlap is not filled]

---

To make the correct clip, I need to select an area from four overlapping ellipses and a rectangle. I believe that it is not possible without altering the stroke direction of some of the ellipses!? It would not help to make clip use `even odd rule`.

**Question:**
How do I not fill the intersection of two overlapping circles(ellipses) without the `even odd rule`?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \fill (0,0) circle (2) (1,1) circle (2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Desired output:
[image: Overlapping circles without intersection fill]

I can not find anything in the manual about changing the stroke direction. Can it be done? Maybe there is an other way?

**Edit:**
I just found that for my original purpose, it *does* help to make clip use `even odd rule` (can be done with a scope). -but my question is still the same -is it possible without.

Comment: How technical are you prepared to go? My ’spath3` library contains code for reversing paths, but it was designed as a utility library for other packages to build on rather than with a simple user interface so a solution using it may not look all that elegant.

Comment: @AndrewStacey: I am not willing to dive into some technical code. I was hoping for an option, or some trick that reverses the stroke direction or otherwise makes the fill of a circle change parity. If you can explain that it is not possible without being technical or a lot of code, I will accept that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stroke direction of `rectangle` is relative to the provided points. For example, in your first code, try `(5,2) rectangle (7,0)` instead of `(5,0) rectangle (7,2)`. With `circle`, you can use `circle(-2 and 2)` instead of `circle(2)`.

```tex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[fill=red]  (0,0) circle (1) (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
  \draw[fill=green] (4,-1) rectangle (6,1) (5,2) rectangle (7,0);
  \draw[fill=blue] (9,0) circle (1) (9.5,0.5) circle (-1 and 1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So simple - thanks. Is `circle (\rx and \ry)` the same as `ellipse (\rx and \ry)`?

Comment: Note that the `circle (x and y)` syntax is depreciated, you should use `circle[x radius=..., y radius=]` instead.

Comment: @AndrewStacey: Thanks. I reread the manual about circles. I will try to remember using the better notation on this site. -also I did not know that it was possible to give two different radii to `circle` - making `ellipse` superfluous.

Answer (score 3):

My [`spath3`](https://ctan.org/pkg/spath3) library was designed to do low level manipulation of paths, including reversing the stroke direction.  The public interface is a little basic as the intention was to provide functionality that could be used in other packages (such as the `knot` and `calligraphy` TikZ libraries).  Here's a proof of concept.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/568999/86}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{spath3}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[save spath=circle1]  (0,0) circle[radius=2];
\path[save spath=circle2] (1,1) circle[radius=2];
 \fill (0,0) [insert spath=circle1] (1,1) [insert reverse spath=circle2];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Reversed path used in a fill]

**Edit by OP:**
I believe that `spath3` syntax has been updated. A working code is now:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{spath3}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[spath/save=circle1]  (0,0) circle[radius=2];
\path[spath/save=circle2] (1,1) circle[radius=2];
\fill (0,0) [spath/insert=circle1] (1,1) [spath/insert reverse=circle2];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```