# Using clip in a annulus

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the code of a Tikz picture below. How can I clip in the up gray annulus of the stator draw? I already tried with `\clip (0,0,\H) circle (\r) circle (\R);` but the result is not how I want:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

% isometric axes
\pgfmathsetmacro\xx{1/sqrt(2)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\xy{1/sqrt(6)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\zz{sqrt(2/3)}
\tikzset{isometric/.style={x={(-\xx cm,-\xy cm)},y={(\xx cm,-\xy cm)},z={(0cm,\zz cm)}}}

% parameters
\def\nc{24}   % number of cogs (multiple of 4, at least 8)
\def\H {1}    % total height
\def\h {0.25} % cog height
\def\R {2}    % outer radius
\def\r {1.5}  % inner radius
\def\upper {(0,0,\H) circle (\r);(0,0,\H) circle (\R);}

\pgfmathtruncatemacro\nw{\nc/4} % number of cog walls per quadrant
\pgfmathsetmacro\a {180/\nc}    % step angle
\pgfmathsetmacro\is{135+2*\a}   % inner part step
\pgfmathsetmacro\il{315-4*\a}   % inner part last iteration
\pgfmathsetmacro\os{-45+2*\a}   % outer part step
\pgfmathsetmacro\ol{135-4*\a}   % outer part last iteration
\tikzset
{
  inner/.style={fill=gray!30},
  outer/.style={fill=gray!10},
  cogs/.style= {fill=gray!50},
  top/.style=  {fill=gray!20},
  cut/.style=  {color=red!60, dashed},
}



\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=1,xscale=1, isometric,line join=round,line cap=round]
% inner cogs side walls
\foreach\i in{-\nw,...,\nw}
{
  \pgfmathsetmacro\j{4*\nw-\i}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\k{6*\nw+\i}
  \draw[cogs] (\a*\j:\R) -- (\a*\j:\r) --++ (0,0,\h) --++ (\a*\j:\R-\r) -- cycle;
  \draw[cogs] (\a*\k:\R) -- (\a*\k:\r) --++ (0,0,\h) --++ (\a*\k:\R-\r) -- cycle;
}
% inner part
\draw[inner] (135:\r) foreach\i in {135,\is,...,\il}
  {arc (\i:\i+\a:\r)        --++ (0,0,\h) arc (\i+\a:\i+2*\a:\r) --++ (0,0,-\h)}
   arc (315-2*\a:315-\a:\r) --++ (0,0,\h) arc (315-\a:315:\r)    --++ (0,0, \H-\h)
   arc (315:135:\r) -- cycle;
% outer cogs side walls
\foreach\i in{-\nw,...,\nw}
{
  \pgfmathsetmacro\j{-\i+2*\nw}
  \draw[cogs] (\a*\i:\R) -- (\a*\i:\r) --++ (0,0,\h) --++ (\a*\i:\R-\r) -- cycle;
  \draw[cogs] (\a*\j:\R) -- (\a*\j:\r) --++ (0,0,\h) --++ (\a*\j:\R-\r) -- cycle;
}
% outer part
\draw[outer] (-45:\R) foreach\i in {-45,\os,...,\ol}
  {arc (\i:\i+\a:\R)        --++ (0,0,\h) arc (\i+\a:\i+2*\a:\R) --++ (0,0,-\h)}
   arc (135-2*\a:135-\a:\R) --++ (0,0,\h) arc (135-\a:135:\R)    --++ (0,0,\H-\h)
   arc (135:-45:\R) -- cycle;


% top part
\draw[even odd rule,top] (0,0,\H) circle (\R) (0,0,\H) circle (\r);

\foreach \i in {3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17}
\draw[even odd rule,cut] ({\R*cos(((\i *\a)+((\i+1)*\a))/2)},{\R*sin(((\i *\a)+((\i+1)*\a))/2)},0.25) -- ({\R*cos(((\i *\a)+((\i+1)*\a))/2)},{\R*sin(((\i *\a)+((\i+1)*\a))/2)},\H);

\foreach \i in {4,6,8,10,12,14,16}
\draw[even odd rule,cut] ({\R*cos(((\i *\a)+((\i+1)*\a))/2)},{\R*sin(((\i *\a)+((\i+1)*\a))/2)},0) -- ({\R*cos(((\i *\a)+((\i+1)*\a))/2)},{\R*sin(((\i *\a)+((\i+1)*\a))/2)},\H);

\foreach \i in {27,29,31,33,35,37}
\draw[even odd rule,cut] ({\r*cos(((\i *\a)+((\i+1)*\a))/2)},{\r*sin(((\i *\a)+((\i+1)*\a))/2)},0.25) -- ({\r*cos(((\i *\a)+((\i+1)*\a))/2)},{\r*sin(((\i *\a)+((\i+1)*\a))/2)},\H);

\foreach \i in {28,30,32,34,36,38}
\draw[even odd rule,cut] ({\r*cos(((\i *\a)+((\i+1)*\a))/2)},{\r*sin(((\i *\a)+((\i+1)*\a))/2)},0) -- ({\r*cos(((\i *\a)+((\i+1)*\a))/2)},{\r*sin(((\i *\a)+((\i+1)*\a))/2)},\H);





\begin{scope}
\clip (0,0,\H) circle (\r) circle (\R);
\foreach \i in {3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17}
\draw[even odd rule,cut] ({\R*cos(((\i *\a)+((\i+1)*\a))/2)},{\R*sin(((\i *\a)+((\i+1)*\a))/2)},\H) -- ({\R*cos(-(((\i *\a)+((\i+1)*\a))/2))},{\R*sin(-(((\i *\a)+((\i+1)*\a))/2))},\H);

\foreach \i in {4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,19,20,21}
\draw[even odd rule,cut] ({\R*cos(((\i *\a)+((\i+1)*\a))/2)},{\R*sin(((\i *\a)+((\i+1)*\a))/2)},\H) -- ({\R*cos(-(((\i *\a))+((\i+1)*\a))/2)},{\R*sin(-(((\i *\a)+((\i+1)*\a)))/2)},\H);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1853/140722

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
\clip (0,0,\H) circle[radius=\R] (0,0,\H) circle[x radius=-\r, y radius=\r];
```

To understand this, see:
[Reverse TikZ stroke direction to use with fill rules](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/568999/reverse-tikz-stroke-direction-to-use-with-fill-rules)

Result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

% isometric axes
\pgfmathsetmacro\xx{1/sqrt(2)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\xy{1/sqrt(6)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\zz{sqrt(2/3)}
\tikzset{isometric/.style={x={(-\xx cm,-\xy cm)},y={(\xx cm,-\xy cm)},z={(0cm,\zz cm)}}}

% parameters
\def\nc{24}   % number of cogs (multiple of 4, at least 8)
\def\H {1}    % total height
\def\h {0.25} % cog height
\def\R {2}    % outer radius
\def\r {1.5}  % inner radius
\def\upper {(0,0,\H) circle (\r);(0,0,\H) circle (\R);}

\pgfmathtruncatemacro\nw{\nc/4} % number of cog walls per quadrant
\pgfmathsetmacro\a {180/\nc}    % step angle
\pgfmathsetmacro\is{135+2*\a}   % inner part step
\pgfmathsetmacro\il{315-4*\a}   % inner part last iteration
\pgfmathsetmacro\os{-45+2*\a}   % outer part step
\pgfmathsetmacro\ol{135-4*\a}   % outer part last iteration
\tikzset
{
  inner/.style={fill=gray!30},
  outer/.style={fill=gray!10},
  cogs/.style= {fill=gray!50},
  top/.style=  {fill=gray!20},
  cut/.style=  {color=red!60, dashed},
}



\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=1,xscale=1, isometric,line join=round,line cap=round]
% inner cogs side walls
\foreach\i in{-\nw,...,\nw}
{
  \pgfmathsetmacro\j{4*\nw-\i}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\k{6*\nw+\i}
  \draw[cogs] (\a*\j:\R) -- (\a*\j:\r) --++ (0,0,\h) --++ (\a*\j:\R-\r) -- cycle;
  \draw[cogs] (\a*\k:\R) -- (\a*\k:\r) --++ (0,0,\h) --++ (\a*\k:\R-\r) -- cycle;
}
% inner part
\draw[inner] (135:\r) foreach\i in {135,\is,...,\il}
  {arc (\i:\i+\a:\r)        --++ (0,0,\h) arc (\i+\a:\i+2*\a:\r) --++ (0,0,-\h)}
   arc (315-2*\a:315-\a:\r) --++ (0,0,\h) arc (315-\a:315:\r)    --++ (0,0, \H-\h)
   arc (315:135:\r) -- cycle;
% outer cogs side walls
\foreach\i in{-\nw,...,\nw}
{
  \pgfmathsetmacro\j{-\i+2*\nw}
  \draw[cogs] (\a*\i:\R) -- (\a*\i:\r) --++ (0,0,\h) --++ (\a*\i:\R-\r) -- cycle;
  \draw[cogs] (\a*\j:\R) -- (\a*\j:\r) --++ (0,0,\h) --++ (\a*\j:\R-\r) -- cycle;
}
% outer part
\draw[outer] (-45:\R) foreach\i in {-45,\os,...,\ol}
  {arc (\i:\i+\a:\R)        --++ (0,0,\h) arc (\i+\a:\i+2*\a:\R) --++ (0,0,-\h)}
   arc (135-2*\a:135-\a:\R) --++ (0,0,\h) arc (135-\a:135:\R)    --++ (0,0,\H-\h)
   arc (135:-45:\R) -- cycle;


% top part
\draw[even odd rule,top] (0,0,\H) circle (\R) (0,0,\H) circle (\r);

\foreach \i in {3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17}
\draw[even odd rule,cut] ({\R*cos(((\i *\a)+((\i+1)*\a))/2)},{\R*sin(((\i *\a)+((\i+1)*\a))/2)},0.25) -- ({\R*cos(((\i *\a)+((\i+1)*\a))/2)},{\R*sin(((\i *\a)+((\i+1)*\a))/2)},\H);

\foreach \i in {4,6,8,10,12,14,16}
\draw[even odd rule,cut] ({\R*cos(((\i *\a)+((\i+1)*\a))/2)},{\R*sin(((\i *\a)+((\i+1)*\a))/2)},0) -- ({\R*cos(((\i *\a)+((\i+1)*\a))/2)},{\R*sin(((\i *\a)+((\i+1)*\a))/2)},\H);

\foreach \i in {27,29,31,33,35,37}
\draw[even odd rule,cut] ({\r*cos(((\i *\a)+((\i+1)*\a))/2)},{\r*sin(((\i *\a)+((\i+1)*\a))/2)},0.25) -- ({\r*cos(((\i *\a)+((\i+1)*\a))/2)},{\r*sin(((\i *\a)+((\i+1)*\a))/2)},\H);

\foreach \i in {28,30,32,34,36,38}
\draw[even odd rule,cut] ({\r*cos(((\i *\a)+((\i+1)*\a))/2)},{\r*sin(((\i *\a)+((\i+1)*\a))/2)},0) -- ({\r*cos(((\i *\a)+((\i+1)*\a))/2)},{\r*sin(((\i *\a)+((\i+1)*\a))/2)},\H);





\begin{scope}
\clip (0,0,\H) circle[radius=\R] (0,0,\H) circle[x radius=-\r, y radius=\r];
\foreach \i in {3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17}
\draw[even odd rule,cut] ({\R*cos(((\i *\a)+((\i+1)*\a))/2)},{\R*sin(((\i *\a)+((\i+1)*\a))/2)},\H) -- ({\R*cos(-(((\i *\a)+((\i+1)*\a))/2))},{\R*sin(-(((\i *\a)+((\i+1)*\a))/2))},\H);

\foreach \i in {4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,19,20,21}
\draw[even odd rule,cut] ({\R*cos(((\i *\a)+((\i+1)*\a))/2)},{\R*sin(((\i *\a)+((\i+1)*\a))/2)},\H) -- ({\R*cos(-(((\i *\a))+((\i+1)*\a))/2)},{\R*sin(-(((\i *\a)+((\i+1)*\a)))/2)},\H);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Ring with clipped red lines]