# Decoration for self crossing lines/curves

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations, pgf-decorations

Is it possible to define a decoration/postaction, for drawing a double line so that a self intersecting line will draw on top of itself?
To show what I mean see these spirals:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[red, double=yellow, thick, domain=0:pi, smooth, samples=200] plot (\x, {cos(10*\x r)} , {sin(10*\x r)} );
\begin{scope}[yshift=-3cm]
\foreach \i in {1,...,10}
\draw[red, double=yellow, thick, domain=pi*(\i-1)/10:pi*\i/10, smooth, samples=200] plot (\x, {cos(10*\x r)} , {sin(10*\x r)} );
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Two spirals]

The top spiral shows the effect of a normal double line and the bottom spiral shows the desired result. I wish the result done with just one `\draw` command to avoid rendering artefacts and make the `smooth` option work across the whole spiral.

Ultimately, I want to be able to use white as the outer color and thereby creating a crossing effect. To be able to better answer questions on this site e.g.
[Conical and cylindircal spirals](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/572310/conical-and-cylindircal-spirals/572499#572499)

I was thinking that it should be possible by making the double on small segments of the path as it is being drawn. A naive approach like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary {decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[yellow, 
decorate, decoration={zigzag, segment length=1mm, amplitude=0mm},
preaction={draw, ultra thick, red},
domain=0:pi, samples=200] plot (\x, {cos(10*\x r)} , {sin(10*\x r)} );
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

does not work as the preaction is applied to the whole path and not the segments.

**A even better solution would be if the path could `clip` itself, so that the crossing would look nice on a non-white background.** - Probably quite complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way with the `show path construction`.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[path decomposition/.style={%
    postaction={decoration={show path construction,
    lineto code={
      \draw[#1]  (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast);
    },
    curveto code={
      \draw[#1]  (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) .. controls
        (\tikzinputsegmentsupporta) and (\tikzinputsegmentsupportb)
        ..(\tikzinputsegmentlast) ;
    },
    closepath code={
      \draw[#1]  (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast) {closepath};} }
    ,decorate}}]
\draw[red, double=yellow, thick, domain=0:pi, smooth, samples=200,
path decomposition={red, double=yellow, thick}] plot (\x, {cos(10*\x r)} , {sin(10*\x r)} );
\begin{scope}[yshift=-3cm]
\foreach \i in {1,...,10}
\draw[red, double=yellow, thick, domain=pi*(\i-1)/10:pi*\i/10, smooth, samples=200] plot (\x, {cos(10*\x r)} , {sin(10*\x r)} );
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Please note that there are already complete styles for this in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/449706).

Comment: You are *fast* :o) . Also thanks for the link - I will study it.

Comment: It is a very beautiful solution. At first, I could not see how it could possible be more elegant. -but at closer look, there are many rendering artefacts. It can be spotted on your picture, but it is easier seen with black on white. There are many hairline spikes and gaps. I do not understand the spikes(I believe that double is implemented by drawing fat line first and then center - the center should not be able to poke out.). Maybe the gaps could be corrected with `shorten`!?

Comment: I will probably accept your answer, but I would like your opinion on wether the artefacts are possibly corrected.

Comment: `shorten <=-0.002 pt` makes it better

Comment: @hpekristiansen I do not know if the artifacts can be corrected easily. They seem also to be a bit viewer dependent. Another way to go is to use the `knots` library. However, I am not sure if this is ideal for the scenario you want to use it on. IMHO the 3d coil from the linked answer might be a reasonable alternative. (I also tried to shorten the stretches by a negative amount but the result does not look fully convincing on all viewers I tried.)

Comment: Maybe it is better to replacing `\draw[red, double=yellow, ` with `\path[` . -so that it is not drawn twice. I am not sure that it does anything.

Comment: By not having the `smooth` option, it is very visible that the line segments are not mitred. In the same way will individual curved segments not end in the exact same angle as the next curve segment starts. Conclusion: The artefacts are real and not *just* viewer rendering.

Comment: @hpekristiansen The artifacts are real, of course, since the path gets decomposed, but how they look like does depend on the viewer. I get very different results with `acroread` and `preview`.

Comment: One last question: Do you know what controls the segment length? I can not find it in the manual.

Comment: @hpekristiansen The decoration really just hooks into the segments as they get created by the path. In your case, the segment length is controlled by `samples=200`, which produces 199 plot segments, each of which is a Bezier curve since you use the `smooth` key. That is, the segment length is entirely specified by the path you decorate.

Answer (score 4):

The [`knots`](https://ctan.org/pkg/spath3) TikZ library handles this sort of thing.  There's a slight issue with using the `plot` drawing command because that creates a *lot* of very short lines and that's not great for the way that `knots` works since it looks for intersections between subpaths.  Fortunately, using the [`hobby`](https://ctan.org/pkg/hobby) library I can reduce the number of samples considerably as it interpolates using bezier curves.

The `knots` library works by redrawing just part of the curve at the intersections to produce the overpass effect.

Using the double option with the `knots` library can produce artefacts when the PDF is viewed (but not when it is printed).  The method for removing them is detailed at [problem with "crop circles" in tikz knot library](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/188447/86)

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/572737/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{knots,hobby}

\tikzset{
  basic strand/.style={
    red,
    double=yellow,
    double distance=1pt,
  },
  crossing strand/.style={
    line width=1.8pt,
    only when rendering/.style={%
      draw=yellow,%
      line width=1pt,
      double=none,
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[use Hobby shortcut]
\begin{knot}[
  consider self intersections=true,
  ignore endpoint intersections=false,
  background colour=red,
  every intersection/.style={
    crossing strand
  },
  only when rendering/.style={
    basic strand
  },
  clip width=1
]
\strand (0,1,0) \foreach \x in {1,...,80} { .. (\x/80*pi, {cos(22.5*\x )} , {sin(22.5*\x )} ) };
\end{knot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Coil with overlay effect]

Comment: Cool - I have not used knots or hobby before. -I need to read the manual. I guess, that no amount of screaming and jumping, will completely eliminate artefacts as also shown here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/572839/joining-tikz-paths-seamlessly/572882#572882 .-but this is definitely an improvement.

Comment: @hpekristiansen Actually, those artefacts can be easily removed.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/188447/86

Comment: @hpekristiansen I've modified it to use the non-artefact code.