Drawing sphere with 6 points using TiKz
So I am trying to get an image going using TiKz, what I have in mind is as follows

What I am missing is the correct labels, mainly the greek letters eta, xi, and zeta, also I'm looking for arrows pointing to 0, 1 and $\infty$ with them appearing to be on the surface of the sphere, I thought a bit about this and it could be as a part of an  elipse but as is obvious I do not know how to accomplish it. 
Here's the code I have so far, as well as the rendered image:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    % Define sphere
    \draw (0,0) circle [radius=1];
    % Draw equator
    \draw[dashed] (90:1) arc (90:270:1);
    % Draw ellipse
    \draw[dashed] (1,0) arc (0:180:1 and 0.3);
    \draw (-1,0) arc (180:360:1 and 0.3);
    % Draw points
    \foreach \angle/\label/\pos in {30/A/above left, 150/B/above left, 90/C/above, -30/X/below left, -150/Y/below left, -90/Z/below} {
        \node (\label) at (\angle:1) [circle, fill, inner sep=0.03cm, label=\pos:\label] {};
    }
    % Draw arrows
    \foreach \from/\to in {A/B, B/C, C/X} {
        \draw[->] (\from) -- (\to);
    }
    % Draw dashed lines for perspective
    \draw[dashed] (1,0) -- (B);
    \draw[dashed] (1,0) -- (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Pretty much only the point C is on the correct position, when I try to put $\infty$ in it I get the error
Missing \endcsname inserted.                                                  
<to be read again>                                                              
                   \infty                                                       
l.17     }                

Any advice or pointers would be much appreciated.

Welcome. // The problem seems to be that in your first loop it would expand (only for the \label) to \node ($\infty$) at (\angle:1) [circle, fill, inner sep=0.03cm, label=\pos:$\infty$] {}; , which doesn't make much sense for a node name ...

To draw surface arcs without using tikz-3dplot requires a bit of calculation.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/408245/clipping-more-complicated-shapes-in-tikz/410379?r=SearchResults&s=12%7C5.3307#410379 for example.

Here's a way to have your hand drawing, while your screencopy follows in a similar way. Some remarks:

in general, don't try too much in one go; loops have a hard time here, because you try combining different things
you didn't us the 3D lib, so I dropped it
the radius could be a constant, while with some more patience calc can be introduced here
styles are your friend, i.e. to make code easier to grasp
dots here are just filled nodes, which have a circle as their shape
on the ellipse I put two extra nodes at different pos, where their names are really relevant
syntactically a path starts with \, ends with ; and everything in between are actions to perform (hence these nodes don't start with \)
the other points coudl have been coordinates, too; names are what I'm after
see the polar notation, which once again indicates some thoughts needed for the radius-constant
now putting labels and drawing bent lines is almost a no-brainer


\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}  % adding some border
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{3d}                    % it's not used
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}            % for nicer arrow tips

% ~~~ constants ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\rd[0]{2}
\newcommand\rdm[0]{(-2,0)}  % can be done better with calc

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}%[scale=2] % that's not too good to do
    [
        dot/.style={fill=black,circle,inner sep=1pt},
        as/.style={anchor=south},
        ae/.style={anchor=east},
        aw/.style={anchor=west},
        >={Stealth},            % replacing all arrow tips
    ]
    % Define sphere
    \draw (0,0) circle [radius=\rd{}];
    % Draw equator
    \draw[dashed] (90:\rd{}) arc (90:270:\rd{});
    % Draw ellipse + adding some nodes (with names)
    \draw[dashed] (\rd{},0) arc (0:180:\rd{} and 0.3);
    \draw \rdm{} arc (180:360:\rd{} and 0.3) 
            node[pos=.55,dot] (Zero) {}
            node[pos=.70,dot] (One) {};
    
    % ~~~ other points ~~~~~~~~~
    \node[dot] (Inf) at (0,\rd{}) {};
    \node[dot] (Eta) at (130:1.5) {};
    \node[dot] (Ksi) at (220:1.0) {};
    \node[dot] (Zet) at (340:1.6) {};
    
    % ~~~ putting labels ~~~~~~~
    \node[as] at (Inf) {$\infty$};
    \node[as] at (Zero){$0$};
    \node[as] at (One) {$1$};
    
    \node[ae] at (Eta) {$\eta$};
    \node[ae] at (Ksi) {$\xi$};
    \node[aw] at (Zet) {$\zeta$};
    
    % ~~~ arrows: bender was here ~~~~~
    \draw[->] (Zet) -- (One);               % start this way
    \draw[->] (Eta) to[bend left] (Inf);    % refine later
    \draw[->] (Ksi) to[bend right] (Zero);

    
%    % Draw points
%    \foreach \angle/\label/\pos in {30/A/above left, 150/B/above left, 90/C/above, -30/X/below left, -150/Y/below left, -90/Z/below} {
%        \node (\label) at (\angle:1) [circle, fill, inner sep=0.03cm, label=\pos:\label] {};
%    }
%    % Draw arrows
%    \foreach \from/\to in {A/B, B/C, C/X} {
%        \draw[->] (\from) -- (\to);
%    }
%    % Draw dashed lines for perspective
%    \draw[dashed] (1,0) -- (B);
%    \draw[dashed] (1,0) -- (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


A very thorough explanation. I appreciate you explaining the process, it was very educational.

Fine :) Successful Tikzing and texing ;-)
