Sphere with a randomly marked region and an equatorial circle
I'm working with spheres in 3D and would like to draw a sphere with an open region $U$ with color green and enclosed closed region $E$ filled with color red such that $E \subset U$. And a vector $x$ on the sphere with the dotted equatorial circle, however this circle should disappear in the region $U$.
There is a similar post about this: Random closed line on a 3d sphere.
I'd be gladly for any codes/tips/resources where I can learn to do this. Thank you

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/408245/clipping-more-complicated-shapes-in-tikz

Do you need to use 3D tikz-plotting (like x,y,z coordinates), or do you just need the resemblance of 3Dness?

@LorenzoCarozzo resemblance is enough, thanks
